# Up navigation to parent goes always to main activity

Tags: android, navigation, android-activity

I have Activity A where I start Activity C that has parent Activity C.
The issue is that touching Up in actions in Activity C takes me to my MainActivity instead of Activity B.

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.ilikeq.android.BActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_threads"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.ilikeq.android.CActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_thread"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName="com.ilikeq.android.BActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.ilikeq.android.BActivity" />
    </activity>
```

In Activity C:

```
        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
```

Activity B:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_threads);

        ListView list = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.list_threads);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<Thread>(this, R.layout.view_list_item_thread, new Thread[] { new Thread(), new Thread(), new Thread(), new Thread(), new Thread(), new Thread(), new Thread(), new Thread(), new Thread() }) {

            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                if (view == null) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_list_item_thread, null);
                }

                return view;
            }

        });

        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                itemClicked();
            }
        });
    }

    public void itemClicked() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThreadActivity.class);
        this.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        this.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.threads, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Activity A:

```
public void onMessageClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThreadsActivity.class);
    this.startActivity(intent);
}
```

It also does wrong animation - the one like new child activity is being shown (appear effect) instead of finished (disappear effect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you need to clear the stack of activities and start a new task. This is achieved by adding flags to your activity. 
You might get some useful insights here - http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

I think these are important in your case:

- FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
- FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK

You can also try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            // chose to which activity to go to 
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, PreviousActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;

    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

EDIT:

In your manifest file, add meta tag for parent activity:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.app.ActivityB"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_b"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.app.ActivityC"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_activity_c"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.app.ActivityB" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="ActivityB" />
    </activity>
```

Moreover, as I suspected the other day, you have an adapter in your MainActivity - nothing wrong with that, but the way you use it is not efficient. I suggest you move it out in a separate file and create a custom adapter that extends ArrayAdapter. Then you can use the ViewHolder pattern to optimize it - in this way you can also maintain current position at the list even if you go back back and forth other activities.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView
Check out the ViewHolder sections.

Comment: this takes me to the right screen, thats fine, but it doesnt seem like right solution to me, why it diesnt work properly when I have parent activities defined? BTW, the animation is still like new activity is starting. Besides, it creates new instance of the activity, I wanna use return back to the scroll position he was before.

Comment: Well yes, technically this creates the activity again. Does the previous activity have an adapter of some sort? You can maintain scroll position through the adapter itself, and i think that's the recommended way.

Comment: Well, as I said, this doesnt seem like right solution since I have defined parent activity and this particular solution animates the Previous screen as showing it over the current instead of collapsing the current.

Comment: well then keep the same solution, just remove the two flags of the intent. In that case it will respect the parent activity and animate the corresponding animation. But if you want to maintain a concrete position at the previous screen, then you are asking for something completely different.

Comment: Still, the issue here is that it doesnt respect parentActivity specified in AndroidManifest, why?

Comment: I can't tell you why when you have given us only a onOptionsItemSelected from just one activity.. I can't know what is happening in the other activity unless you edit your post to include it there.

Comment: I did edit my answer to include relevant code from all 3 activities.

Comment: No, I still have no valid solution.

Comment: Thanks, it works. Even the animations are correct. What was the issue?

Comment: I am glad it works now! Your manifest file did not have the meta-data for parent activity. If that is solved then, please mark it as such :) Thanks!

Comment: Ok, its weird. So If I understand it correctly, I need to define parent activity using meta-tags from the top to the bottom for it to work properly?

Comment: The meta-data is to support versions 4.0 and lower. I don't know what API level are you compiling with, but if your minimum target API is lower than 4.0, maybe that's why. So yes - you need to add the meta-tags in every activity which has a parent.

Comment: Gradle says this - "compileSdkVersion 19", "minSdkVersion 15" and "targetSdkVersion 19"

Comment: Oops, this the way around - meta is needed to support API 4.0+ :) Just read it here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html  (Search for meta-data)

Comment: Lol, I see. I thought same thing tho. Ok, every day is about learning new stuff. Thank again :)